# Springboot 3 isn't creating the tables in my db migrations folder?

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I'm using springboot 3 and afaik it already has flyway by default. When I'm trying to run my java app using `./gradlew bootRun`, it is able to run without errors, but when I try to save an entry into my database, it says that the table wasn't created.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "destination" does not exist
```

I'm suspecting, it's not creating the table in my db migration folder.

Here's what my db migration folder structure looks like:
[image]

The contents of `V1__create_destination_table.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE destination (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
    name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    address character varying(10000) NOT NULL,
    destination_type character varying(255),
    phone_number character varying(255),
    image_link character varying(10000),
    business_link character varying(10000),
    version bigint NOT NULL,
    dateCreated timestamp without time zone,

    CONSTRAINT destination_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Here's what my `application.properties` look like:

```
server.port=${CDOYPBE_PORT}

management.security.enabled = false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,beans,metrics,trace,trace

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.batch_versioned_data=true

spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.flyway.url=${CDOYPBE_DB_URL}
spring.flyway.user=${CDOYPBE_DB_USER_NAME}
spring.flyway.password=${CDOYPBE_DB_PASSWORD}
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migrations
spring.flyway.schemas=migrations

spring.datasource.url=${CDOYPBE_DB_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${CDOYPBE_DB_USER_NAME}
spring.datasource.password=${CDOYPBE_DB_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

My `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'groovy'
}

group = 'com.zeitgeist'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:3.1.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.3-groovy-4.0'
}
```

Can someone enlighten me how to solve this?

Comment: you need explicitly define flyway as a project dependency: `implementation ‘org.flywaydb:flyway-core`

Comment: wow i think that solved it. put it as an official response so i can declare it as the answer.